# How do I prevent opacity shades from getting darker when overlapping each other in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, transparency

Here is my current project:
[image]

How do I prevent the darker black underneath the bowl? Both layers are at 50% opacity at #000000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I figured it out. I just removed the opacity for both layers, merged them, and put back the opacity. It's just one shade of gray now!

Comment: You could have merged them without changing opacity first. You could also have just you know coloroed them gray. Or you coukd have grouped them and applied the opacity  to th group and set the opacity options....

Comment: or you could have simply deleted the darker piece directly under the bowl, and filled the shadow with opaque grey.  Shapes filled with semi-transparent colour fills will always get darker where they overlap